# FuelSDK SentEvent Timeouts

Tags: fuel-sdk, timeout

I read another post here that said if you are getting a timeout then extend the timeout property in the ET_Client.cs file. I searched for timeout in that file but found nothing. Anyone know where I can find it?

Also, I read that the SDK will only return 2500 results when you do a retrieval. How do you get the rest of your data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For getting more results you can use the 'get more results' method.

this is detailed in the GIT repository.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/objsamples/sample_bounceevent.py

as for the timeout, i'm after finding out the same, if i get i'll post here.